# ViewPager inside horizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-viewpager, horizontalscrollview

I have ViewPager inside HorizontalScrollView. I want to dispatch motion events from ViewPager to HorizontalScrollView when I'm on first page

```
private final SimpleOnGestureListener viewPagerListener = new SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(final MotionEvent e1, final MotionEvent e2,
            final float distanceX, final float distanceY) {

        final RevealControl reveal = (RevealControl) getActivity()
                .findViewById(R.id.revealView);

        if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0 && distanceX < 0) {
            return reveal.dispatchTouchEvent(e2);
        }

        return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
    }
};
```

I got the function above, but sometimes my scrollView is scrolling to much. Maybe there is some other way to dispatch my event.

Comment: You want to display more than one viewpager in one screen? Somehow like a gallery?

Comment: "I have ViewPager inside HorizontalScrollView" -- why?

Comment: I trying to implement some kind of swiping reveal control like on facebook.

Comment: @Orest I want to achieve something similar. Did you work it out? Thanks !

Comment: Yeah, but it was non-trivial I thinking if I should post all the code here